# Minimum Problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$f(m) = \frac{-1}{2}m^2 + \frac{1}{\beta}\int^m_{0} g^{-1}(s)ds.$$

where $\beta$ is a positive constant, $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function which positive derivative. In particular, it is strictly increasing and globally lipschitz with $g(0) = 0$, that is, there is $k_1 > 0$ such that $|g(x) - g(y)| \leq k_1|x - y|$, $\forall \ x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $|g(x)| \leq k_1|x|$, $\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Assume $k_1\beta > 1$.

**Affirmation:** $f$ has the a global minimum.

**Attempt:**

I want to show initially that $f$ does have a minimum. If $f$ has a global minimum, then we must have $f'' > 0$. Thus, deriving $f$, we have
$$f''(m) = -1 + \frac{1}{\beta}(g^{-1})'(m) = -1 + \frac{1}{\beta g'(m)}.$$

Now, since $g$ is globally Lipschitz, we must have $|g'(m)| \leq k_1$, from which we conclude that $\frac{1}{\beta k_1} \leq \frac{1}{\beta g'(m)}$. Thus,
$$f''(m) = -1 + \frac{1}{\beta g'(m)} \geq -1 + \frac{1}{k_1 \beta}.$$

From here, we can't conclude anything, since $k_1\beta > 1$, by hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(s) = s/2$ and $\beta = 3$. Note that:

$\bullet$ $g$ is a function which positive derivative;

$\bullet$ $g$ is strictly increasing;

$\bullet$ $g(0) = 0$ and is globally Lipschitz, with constant $k_1 = 1/2$.

So we have $\beta \cdot k_1 = 3/2 > 1$, plus
$$f(m) = -\dfrac{1}{2}m^2 + \dfrac{1}{3}\int_0^m 2sds = -\dfrac{1}{2}m^2 + \dfrac{1}{3}m^2 = -\dfrac{1}{6}m^2 < 0.$$
Therefore, $f$ is a parabola that has no minimum point.

Note: I believe the accounts you want would work for
$$f(m) = \frac{1}{2}m^2 - \frac{1}{\beta}\int^m_{0} g^{-1}(s)ds.$$